# fstream object not recognized by Visual Studio's JIT/Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, fstream

I currently have two files, `globals.h` and `mainmenu.cpp`, which are part of a larger console application meant to simulate a bookstore.

The relevant bits of code can be found below.

---

#### globals.h

```
using std::fstream;

#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

// Other global variables here

extern fstream datafile;

#endif
```

---

#### mainmenu.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>

#include "globals.h"

using namespace std;

fstream datafile;
datafile.open("inventory.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
```

---

For reasons I currently do not understand, Visual Studio is telling me on the `datafile.open()` line that `datafile` "has no storage class or type specifier", and I get the following output when I try to compile:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SerendipityBooksellers, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  mainmenu.cpp
1>c:\path\to\project\mainmenu.cpp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
1>c:\path\to\project\mainmenu.cpp(32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\path\to\project\mainmenu.cpp(32): error C2371: 'datafile' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\path\to\project\globals.h(19) : see declaration of 'datafile'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've been looking around Google and StackOverflow, but can't seem to find any solutions to what I want - what am I doing wrong? The only thing I can think of is that it's complaining that I'm using the generic `fstream` object in place of a `ifstream` and `ostream` object.

Comment: There is no JIT in evidence here, just a standard C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not support code right at the file level. It needs to go in a function. For instance, you could have:

```
fstream datafile;

void open_datafile()
{
    datafile.open("inventory.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
}
```

Obviously, you would need to call the function from somewhere else.

Also, C++ does provide arbitrary constructor execution right at the file level. If you just want the file to be initialized as soon as your program starts, you can use the [fstream constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/fstream/) that accepts the same arguments as open:

```
fstream datafile("inventory.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
```

Keep in mind that the order of construction of global variables is largely unspecified. Globals are initialized in their order of declaration within a single C++ file, but the order between files is unspecified. You should avoid referencing another global variable with a non-trivial constructor from such an expression.

Comment: Well crap. I spent a good 2-3 hours just trying to figure out why. Thanks.

Comment: It happens to even the best of us.

Comment: Oh, and I did try using the constructor - it complained when I added the `ios::in | ios::out` part, though.

Comment: It [works here without issues](https://ideone.com/IDxFnV). Otherwise, `ios::in | ios::out` is the default, so you could try without it.

Comment: "entirely indeterminate" isn't quite true, but it's still a good idea to avoid doing this

Comment: @Edwin use `std::ios::in | std::ios::out`

Comment: @zneak @MattMcNabb I don't know what I had before, but it works now, both with `ios::in | ios::out` and `std::ios::in | std::ios::out`.

Comment: Maybe you put `using namespace std;` where you hadn't previously, or something